# JQuery display list of strings .NET MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net, petapoco

At the bellow code I am trying to fetch a list of strings through JQuery Ajax and .NET framework and display it properly in UI:

**JQuery code:**

```
   $.get("/TargetGroups/GetExistingJobTitles")
        .done(function (data) {
            //code to display properties??
        });
```

**C# code:**

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<string> GetExistingJobTitles()
{
    var foundData = _targetGroupsRepo.GetJobTitles();
    return foundData;
}
```

While debugging indeed, I get a list of strings. It is out of my knowledge how JQuery can expand the returned list and display it in UI let's say in a ul.

Any help is welcome!

Comment: It should return an array, so you can use any of the looping mechanisms that JS has in order to show the data, `for()`, `forEach()` etc...

Comment: It completely depends on the format of parameter `data`. Please post `data` field and exact problem you are facing.

Comment: @KhatamNaayak the returned data as I described is a list of strings. My problem is how to access each value of this list and display it in UI. Thank you.

Comment: @GeorgeD: Your `data` variable is an array.  You can loop over it like any other array.  Have you tried anything at all?  There are a variety of tutorials and examples for jQuery on how to write data to the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Controller Code**

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetExistingJobTitles()
{
var foundData = _targetGroupsRepo.GetJobTitles();
return Json(foundData,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**Jquery**

```
$.get("@Url.Action("GetExistingJobTitles")")
.done(function (data) {
var ulJobTitles = $("#ulJobTitles");
$.each(data, function () {
ulJobTitles.append($("<li></li>").text(this))
}
});
```

The Jquery code should work with the actual Method, i just like using JSON.

**If u want to pass a object instead of a string**

This is the code for a when foundData is a List of objects

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetExistingJobTitles()
{
var foundData = _targetGroupsRepo.GetJobTitles();
var returnObj = foundData.Select(x => new
{
value = x.Id,
text = x.Name
}).ToList();
return Json(returnObj ,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Jquery

```
$.get("@Url.Action("GetExistingJobTitles")")
.done(function (data) {
var selectJobTitles = $("#ulJobTitles");
$.each(data, function () {
selectJobTitles.append($("<option></option>").attr("value", 
this[value]).text(this[text]))
}
});
```

Comment: Diogenh eyxaristw

Answer (score 1):

Your JavaScript/jQuery code are running on two different systems. It is a broad topic to discuss how the data is passing from one system to another and apparently you are not interested in that. Here is my little effort to make you understand the fact you need to understand:

From any server side application, regardless of whether that is C# .Net thing or not, data are send as bytes. When the JS code on the client/browser side receives that code it treats and acts on that according to the MIME type. In your case: your application will return plain text data (String) to the browser and the JS code will interpret or act on that the way you coded. It's up to you what you do with that.

The plain text data is also string in the JS environment. Now, you need to parse the received data into your desired format. The preferred way is to send the data from the web application to the browser or javascript environment as JSON and invoke json parsing method to get the data in desired form. So, if you want to receive array as in your web application then create a json string out of that or let your framework do that. On the receiving side parse the json and loop over the array to create an HTML list.

Let me know if that is enough for your understanding.

Comment: I am going to implement your suggestion. Thank you for the detailed response.